# Can you make a batch file create a google sheet?

Tags: batch-file, google-sheets, cmd, scripting, google-drive-api

Can I create a batch file that runs an SQL query and sends that output to a google sheets doc on g-suites?

I have this so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET SQLCMD="C:\SQLDev\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\extensions"
SET PATH="C:\SQLDev\Audit"
SET SERVER="\PROD"
SET DB="PRODDB"

-i "C:\SQLDev\sqldeveloper\"

SET OUTPUT="C:\Audit.xls"
CD %PATH%
ECHO %date% %time% > %OUTPUT%
for %%f in (*.sql) do (
    %SQLCMD% -S %SERVER% -d %DB% -i %%~f >> %OUTPUT%

PAUSE
```

I'm not really sure if that is possible or not, any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you please outline the research that you did before you posted your question. We wouldn't want to double-up on that effort. Just as a matter of interest, did you come across anything on [JDBC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc).

Answer (score 1):

From your code, I understand you are using Oracle SQL. If that's the case, you can use the Apps Script's [JDBC Connector](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) to connect into your database, execute the queries, and then append data into your sheets.

An example (adapted from the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc)) of this would look like the following:

```js
/**
 * Replace the variables in this block with real values.
 * You can find the "Instance connection name" in the Google Cloud
 * Platform Console, on the instance Overview page.
 */
var connectionName = 'Instance_connection_name';
var user = 'user_name';
var userPwd = 'user_password';
var db = 'database_name';

var dbUrl = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@//' + connectionName + '/' + db;

function importData() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create('Employees dump');
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // Insert sheet headers
  sheet.appendRow(['Name', 'Age', 'Location']);

  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.setMaxRows(1000);
  var cursor = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT name, age, location FROM employees');

  while (cursor.next()) {
    var row = [cursor.getObject('name'),
               cursor.getObject('age'),
               cursor.getObject('location')];
    sheet.appendRow(row);
  }

  results.close();
  stmt.close();
}
```

In this case, JDBC is used to query employee data, and that data is, at the same time, inserted into a Sheets document by use of the [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app), [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) and [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) classes.

It is also important that, if  needs be, you whitelist the following IPs on your server to allow access to it from the script (from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc):

```
64.18.0.0/20
64.233.160.0/19
66.102.0.0/20
66.249.80.0/20
72.14.192.0/18
74.125.0.0/16
173.194.0.0/16
207.126.144.0/20
209.85.128.0/17
216.239.32.0/19
```